# PGF of a visit time.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, moment-generating-functions, analytic-functions

Let $\tau$ be the first visit 1 by an asymmetric random walk $P(+1)=p>0.5, P(-1) = 1-p.$

By the conditioning on the first step, ($\mathbf{E}^p$ means the random walk started at $p$)
\begin{align*}
\varphi(z) := \mathbf{E}^0(z^\tau) = (1 - p)z\mathbf{E}^{-1}(z^\tau) + p z.
\end{align*}
By the strong Markov property applied at the first time to visit zero, $\mathbf{E}^{-1}(z^\tau) = \varphi(z)^2.$ Hence, we reach that $\varphi(z)$ satisfies the "functional equation"
\begin{align*}
(1-p)z \varphi(z)^2 + pz = \varphi(z).
\end{align*}

*This equation is trivially true whenever $\varphi(z) = \infty,$* and when $\varphi(z) < \infty$ it can be solved explicitly using quadratic formula. And for those values of $z$ for which $\varphi(z) < \infty,$ this function is explicitly expressible as $\varphi(z) = \dfrac{1-\sqrt{1-4p(1-p)z^2}}{2(1-p)z}$ (the trivial relation $\varphi(0) = 0$ allows deducing minus is the right choice of sign).

It is easy to see that $0 \leq \varphi(z) \leq 1$ whenever $0 \leq z \leq 1.$ Hence the previous explicit expression applies. However, that expression is well-defined for $z \leq \dfrac{1}{2 \sqrt{p(1 - p)}}.$ A bit of algebra shows that $1 < \dfrac{1}{2 \sqrt{p(1 - p)}}$ (since $p > 0.5$).

> **Question.** It is open the possibility that $\varphi(z) < \infty$ for values of $1 < z \leq \dfrac{1}{2 \sqrt{p(1 - p)}}.$ Any idea on how to show that?

Comment: After talking with some colleagues, I realised this problem is much simpler than not. Simply use Binomial theorem $(1 + t)^\alpha=1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \dbinom{\alpha}{k} t^k$ valid for $|t|<1,$ then apply Abel's lemma.